# Can a site's subdirectory run in its own app pool, with its own web.config?

Tags: .net, web-applications, windows-server-2008, application-pool

I'm running Windows Server 2008 and I am trying to setup the following:

- A website running in a .NET 4.0 Integrated Application Pool (working with its own dedicated app pool
- A subdirectory running in a .NET 2.0 App Pool (I created a sub folder, then did convert to application, and put it into its own app pool)

When running the app in the subdirectory, I get a 500 Server Error saying that the SubDirectory doesn't have permissions to read the web.config of the root site.

I don't want the subdirectory it to read the root site's web.config, since it has its own. I assumed since they are in separate app pools, the subdirectory would read its own web.config and not even necessarily be aware of the root site's web.config.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web.config is always composed of multiple layers; the "master" in the main .NET directory (under CONFIG), the root web.config, and *every layer down* - notably *including* subdirectories within an application.

In short, yes: it needs read access to **any** parent web.config files.

Comment: So I won't be able to run a .NET 2.0 Application if the parent uses .NET 4.0? My thinking behind this is that the Web.config of a .NET 2.0 app is different to a .NET 4.0 app, so it may not understand some .NET 4 specifics? Would an alternative be to setup the subdirectory as a subdomain in it's own site within IIS?

Comment: @Dan - we had some fun doing that back at my last employer; it is a pain, to be honest - especially for parts of the config file that won't be happy in different versions. IIRC we used a trick using condition includes based on the site path; it was complicated and brittle - I'm not sure I recommend it.

Comment: Microsoft's official solution to this problem is to proxy the requests using a mix of Application Request Routing and IIS Rewrite.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing for a full explanation.  Normally the motivation for this is to handle subdirectories that are running on distinct machines, but you can still use this solution across one internal machine.  Personally, I've done this manually by doing a `MapPageRoute` to a simple reverse proxy running inside the main application.

Comment: That said, the reason I did it manually was so that I could generate my layout content on a different server than my primary content.  And yes, this meant that I needed to route form posts to either the parent machine or the proxy machine, depending on the form target.  The solution was surprisingly robust.